# Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Log' not found

Tags: php, magento, fatal-error, magento-1.8

I'm getting the following error in magento administration

**Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Log' not found in /home/website/public_html/app/code/community/Uni/Fileuploader/Block/Adminhtml/Fileuploader/Edit/Tab/Products.php on line 241**

This is a community extension, which has been working fine on my website. The error makes no sense to me, because the line 241 contains just a closing "}" character.

```
class Uni_Fileuploader_Block_Adminhtml_Fileuploader_Edit_Tab_Products extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid {

        ...
        ...
        ...

public function getRowUrl() {
    return '#';
}

public function getGridUrl() {
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/productgrid', array('_current' => true));
}

protected function getFileuploaderData() {
    return Mage::registry('fileuploader_data');
}

protected function _getSelectedProducts() {
    $products = $this->getRequest()->getPost('selected_products');
    if (is_null($products)) {
        $products = explode(',', $this->getFileuploaderData()->getProductIds());
        return (sizeof($products) > 0 ? $products : 0);
    }
    return $products;
}

} // line 241, where error occurs
```

I can post the rest of the code, if you need it.

I noticed that if I upgrade to PHP 5.4 version the error disappears, but since 5.4 version causes other errors on my website, I have to continue using 5.3.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Show us few previous lines of code

Comment: @hindmost, please look at the updated question

Comment: have you tried http://www.netismine.com/magento/fatal-error-class-zend_log-not-found

Comment: @Dushyant Joshi Thanks a lot for that link. I scanned all extension's function names and found that I had to rename getRowUrl() function. I don't understand why this wasn't causing any problems in the past, but anyway.... it's working ok now. Could you post an answer so you can get the reward points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could be  the name of one of the methods in your custom class. 
Take for example the method name is  `getData()` ,

Try searching for generic method names in your script, such as `getData`, which might be reserved by some of Magento’s core classes. I figure that these methods have predefined functionality, which your module is missing support for, and **Zend** then tries to write an exception to Zend log.

**Reference link**: [netismine](http://www.netismine.com/magento/fatal-error-class-zend_log-not-found)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when rewriting a payment method.

```
public function authorize($payment, $amount)
```

Solved rewriting exactly the same main method:

```
public function authorize(Varien_Object $payment, $amount)
```

Magento 1.9.1.0/PHP 5.5